# stacked autoencoder decoder and deconvolutional network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoders, computer-vision

The convolution-deconvolutional architecture can be used for image segmentation or re-construction. These types of tasks can also be done using the architecture of stacked autoencoder-decoder. But what are the underlying differences between these two architecture? Are they generating different types feature hierarchy? What are their respective advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? As I see it, autoencoder is a high-level architectural pattern where your network consists of the encoder part and the decoder part. Convolution/deconvolution is a way to introduce a structure into particular layers of that architecture. Are you asking about the difference b/w using fully connected and convolutional layers in autoencoders?